# How do I prevent MacVim from frequently prompting me to update the buffer?

Tags: vim, macvim

Whenever I am viewing a log file in MacVim on mac os and the log file is being updated by a background server, MacVim will frequently prompt me to "Load file".

[image]

How do I stop this popup? I tried:

```
:set noautoread
```

but that doesn't help.

I want to update the buffer manually (using :e). Thanks.

Comment: If you check `:help W11`, you'll read, at the end of it, the following: `If you get W11 all the time, you may need to disable "Acronis Active Protection" or register Vim as a trusted service/application.`. I suspect this implies you cannot do what you want, not with some option, at least. But I might be wrong.

Comment: I've found [this](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Turning-off-W11-without-autoread-td1180713.html), which points to [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/File_no_longer_available_-_mark_buffer_modified). The former is exactly about the same thing you want to do; I haven't read the latter yet.

Comment: Doing :setl autoread atleast gets rid of the annoying popup which is acceptable to me (but silently keeps loading the file into the buffer)